# onclick event bubbling order

Tags: javascript, html, events

I'm getting a little confused about bubbling.

```
<html>
    <body>
        <div onclick="window.location='http://www.yahoo.com';">
            <span>
                <h3 onclick="window.location='http://www.google.com';">
                    Click me
                </h3>
            </span>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Can someone explain why the page is changed to www.yahoo.com? How do I force it to "bubble" instead of "capture"?

Comment: Because you aren't binding the events, I don't think there's a way to call `e.stopPropagation();` and `window.event.cancelBubble = true;`.

Comment: @Blender I didn't think so either, which was really the point of this question. But AlienWebguy proved us wrong...

Comment: Didn't know that `event` was the default event variable name. Who would've known ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will bubble by default. You can't force capture in IE anyway, do don't use it as a reliable method of event handling.

If you want to stop the event, you'll need to use `event.stopPropagation();` and `event.cancelBubble = true` for IE.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/AlienWebguy/cZWQg/ (used `window.open()` so you can see the effect in jsfiddle).

JQuery will normalize the `event.stopPropagation()` function so it'll work for all browsers.

Example:

```
$('h3').click(function(e){
    e.stopPropagation();
    window.location = 'http://www.google.com';
});
```

Comment: Binding the event in JavsScript is difficult in this case because of my JSP. Is there a way to get around this inline on the elements?

Comment: `<h3 onclick="window.open('http://www.google.com'); event.stopPropagation(); event.cancelBubble = true;">`

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize you could just access the event like that. Thanks man, that was the missing link.

Answer (score 0):

when h3 is clicked, it is also calling the on click of the div, thus redirecting to yahoo instead of google

This might help explain it better than i can:

http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_order.html